# scikit adaboost feature_importance_

Tags: feature-selection, adaboost, ensemble-learning

how exactly does the adaboost algorithm implemented in python assigns feature importances to each feature? I am using it for feature selection and my model performs better on applying feature selection based on the values of feature_importance_ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `feature_importances_` is an attribute available to sklearn's adaboost algorithm when the base classifier is a decision tree. In order to understand how `feature_importances_` are calculated in the adaboost algorithm, you need to first understand how it is calculated for a decision tree classifier.

**Decision Tree Classifier:**

The `feature_importances_` will vary depending on what split criteria you choose. When the split criteria is set to be "entropy": `DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')` the `feature_importances_` are equivalent to the information gain of each feature. [Here is a tutorial](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~shapiro/EE596/notes/InfoGain.pdf) on how to compute the information gain of each feature (slide 7 in particular). When you change the split criteria the `feature_importances_` are no longer equivalent to the information gain, however the steps you take to calculate it are similar to those taken in slide 7 (with the new split criteria used in place of entropy).

**Ensemble Classifiers**:

Now let's return to your original question of how is it determined for the adaboost algorithm. [According to the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#feature-importance):

> This notion of importance can be extended to decision tree ensembles by simply averaging the feature importance of each tree